# How do I use nm to recursively search for specific symbol?

Tags: nm

I would like to find the symbol "start" for example in all object files recursively down from the directory I'm in. I think I can use `nm` or `readelf`, but I'm new to shell and not understanding how to do this from the manual.

Comment: Is the symbol `start` a string (literal) used in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
find . -type f \( -executable -o -name \*.o \) -exec nm -A {} + | grep start
```

This will find all executable files, or object files, and run `nm -A` on them, piping the results to `grep`.

You can adjust this to look for other files. For libraries (`.so` etc.) you should use `nm -A -D` (to list dynamic symbols). The `-A` option makes `nm` repeat the file name on every line, so that the filtered output is still useful.